# How to do batch transaction in Ethereum using web3j

Tags: transactions, web3j, java, batch

I want to do batch transaction using the web3j,So how can I do it? Is there any way or feature web3J provides

Answer (score 0):

It is not implemented yet. But you can have a look at this proposal:

[[WIP][New Feature] Support for batch requests](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/593)